# ¿Cómo obtener los días de un timestamp? - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Necesito obtener la diferencia entre dos timestamp, para ello tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (SELECT CONCAT((SELECT fecha_final FROM resultado_general WHERE codigo_resultado_general = 1000),' ',(SELECT hora_final FROM resultado_general  WHERE codigo_resultado_general = 1000))::timestamp)
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es este: `2 days 16:00:49.723155`

Pero necesito obtener solo el numero de días, es decir, que solo me devuelva `2` del resultado `2 days 16:00:49.723155` ¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola puedes castear los `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` a `DATE`, las operaciones con `DATE` son en dias, ejemplo:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date - 
(SELECT CONCAT((SELECT '2020-11-01'),' ',(select '10:00:00'))::timestamp)::date
```

```
19
```

de lo contrario retornaria:

```
19 days 01:12:39.841448
```